# Call parent form method when returning to parent form from child form

Tags: c#

How do I call a method `LoadGrid` located in a parent form `frmMain` when returning to `frmMain` from a child form?

In `frmMain` the method `LoadGrid` is run at `frmMain` load time to populate a data grid view.  A stored procedure is used in `LoadGrid` to pull the certain (not all) records from SQL data to populate the DGV.  Once frmMain is loaded, it is never loaded again, so `LoadGrid` is never run again and my DGV is never refreshed.

I have created a button on `frmMain` that will run `LoadGrid`.  It works fine, but this takes manual intervention.

My child form is used to approve/clear records that are shown on the `frmMain` DGV.  When returning from the child form, I would like the DGV on `frmMain` "refreshed", but I don't know how to call `LoadGrid` when I return from my child form.

Comment: Call LoadGrid in the OnClosed event of your child form

Answer (score 1):

If your child form is modal, you can just call LoadGrid after the call to ShowDialog. Otherwise, handle the child form's Closed event and call LoadGrid in the event handler.